# MIPS Palindrome Check

Tags: mips, palindrome

I am trying to write a MIPS program that checks if an input string is a palindrome. I tested the string "HelllleH" and when stepping through the program, I saw that during the first loop of PAL_CHECK t0 = 0 but t1 = 104. Logically, t0 = 0 and t1 = 0 also in the first loop. Can someone tell what's wrong in this program?

```
# a0 is input
# a1 is current character we are looking at 
# a2 is length of string
# t0 is character at beginning of string
# t1 is character at end of string
# v0 stores whether string is palindrome or not (0 for false, 1 for true)

ispalindrome:
    addi    $a2, $0, 0  # length counter

FIND_LEN:
    lbu         $a1, 0($a0) # load character into $a1
    beq         $a1, $0, PAL_CHECK  # Break if string is at the end
    addi    $a2, $a2, 1 # increment counter
    addi    $a0, $a0, 1 # increment str address
    j       FIND_LEN

PAL_CHECK:
    # Is palindrome if length is less than 2
    slti    $t0, $a2, 2
    bne         $t0, $0, RETURN_TRUE

    # Check first and last chars to see if they are the same
    lbu         $t0, 0($a0) # first char is t0
    add         $t1, $a2, $a0 # last char is t1
    lbu         $t1, 0($t1)
    bne         $t0, $t1, RETURN_FALSE # if they are not equal, return false

    # continue recursion
    addi    $a2, $a2, -2
    addi    $a0, $a0, 1
    j       PAL_CHECK

RETURN_FALSE:
    addi    $v0, $0, 0
    jr          $ra

RETURN_TRUE:
    addi    $v0, $0, 1
    jr          $ra
```

Answer (score 3):

While finding the length of the string you continually increment `$a0` to point at the next character, until you find the NUL terminator at the end of the string. You never reset `$a0` before the palindrome check loop, so it's still pointing at the NUL terminator when you begin that loop. So you'll actually be comparing data that's past your string.

It would make more sense to implement the check this way (I'm using C to illustrate the idea; I'll leave the MIPS translation to you):

```
a0 = the_string;
a1 = the_string + strlen(the_string) - 1;
while (a1 > a0) {
    if (*a0 != *a1) return false;
    a0++;
    a1--;
}
return true;
```

---

By the way, a terminology nitpick: `# continue recursion`. Your implementation isn't recursive, it's iterative.